# PHP - Can't get a MySQL stored procedure OUT parameter

Tags: php, mysql, procedure

I'm trying to get a value from a string declared inside a stored procedure, so that I can use it in my PHP-code. 
The procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE InsertName
    (IN NewName varchar(50), OUT NewID char(25))
    BEGIN
        DECLARE NewID CHAR(25) DEFAULT (SELECT CONCAT((SELECT unix_timestamp()), (SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * 1000000000000000))));

        INSERT INTO User
        VALUES (NewID, NewName);

    END;    
//
DELIMITER ;
```

The PHP-code that calls the procedure:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];

$sth = $pdo->prepare("CALL InsertName('$name', @idcode)");
$sth->execute();
$sth->closeCursor();

$sth = $pdo->query("SELECT @idcode AS idcode");
$newid = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$idcode=$newid['idcode'];
echo $idcode . " blarg";
```

The page I'm trying to display only shows " blarg", and nothing else. Something is wrong when fetching the OUT parameter. I have also tried with

```
SELECT NewID;
```

in the procedure, it still gives the same result.